# Can XML/XSLT substring-before take more than one match-string as a second argument?

Tags: xml, xslt

XML/XSLT Newb question. I apologise for this. I got handed a chunk of code and asked to 'have a look at this', and I'm not particularly familiar with XSLT :(

I've got an .xsl file that transforms a chunk of story text, and plucks out the first sentence by using the line:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(story,'.')" />
```

It works fine, mostly. The problem is this: if the first sentence ends in a question mark or an exclamation mark, I end up with two sentences.

Is there any way of doing something along the lines of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(story,'.' or '!' or '?')" />
```

Or is there a way of using regex, e.g.

```
/^(.*?)[.?!]\s/
```

...to extract just the very first sentence?

Or am I hugely off the mark and best waiting for the resident XSLT expert to get back? :)

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use? XSLT 2.0 has regular expression support with some XPath functions like `tokenize`, `replace`, and it has `xsl:analyze-string` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string) which you could use for your case to output the first sentence e.g. `<xsl:analyze-string select="story" regex="^(.*?)[.?!]"><xsl:matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:matching-substring></xsl:analyze-string>`.

Answer (score 1):

If your character set for punctuation is relative limited you could map it all to a single character (e.g. period) using the translate function and then use the substring-before. e.g.

`<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(translate(story,'?!','..'),'.')" />`

Edit: I should say in answer to your actual question, no - you can't have a boolean expression as the second argument in substring-before.